# How to connect components of object for segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I am struggling for a while with the following problem:
I have the following gray scale image of plants and I am wondering how to complete the parts where the leafs are 'broken'. I was thinking about dilate and erode, but some of the leafs are curved

[image: example1]
[image: example2]

Comment: Not sure if the fact that some leaves are curved is going to be a problem if you chose to dilate/erode. After all, you can have an isotropic (e.g. circular) structuring element, no? I'm more worried about the structural information you will lose.